# Listing Folders in a Directory C+

Tags: c++, file-io, directory

I am aware that this may well be a duplicate. However, I am struggling to actually get a working answer.

What I am trying to do is list all of the folders in the working directory. Below is some code that I have adapted from the MS website (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx)

This gives the output:

```
Filname:52428
```

I have checked the folder - and there are three folders that I am wanting to list `'Vidoe' 'John' 'David'` I am not sure as to why it is printing out the result above.

I do not want to use Boost - nor to download any third party plugings.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{   
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
//The Directory where the .exe is run from.

    hFind = FindFirstFile(TEXT(".\\Players\\*"), &ffd);
    do
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        bool isDirectory = ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;
        if(isDirectory)
        {
            cout << "DirectoryName: " << *ffd.cFileName << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "FileName: " << *ffd.cFileName << endl;
        }
    }while(FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

**EDIT:** 
I do not have a specific way that I want to do this, all I am wanting to do is output the Folders in the directory - I do  not care how it is done.

Comment: Got the error: FileName: ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
???????????????????????????????????????????????????????=?G???=?g☺
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: You should check the value of hFind before you continue. I am betting that you get back INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE because nothing is found.

Comment: Are you running this inside the Visual Studio Debugger? Remember that the default application path for debugging is not the folder that contains the executable. It is the folder that contains the solution file.

Comment: I am running this using Visual Studio.  I am using the same ".\\Players\\*" string to great effect else where in my program.

Comment: Then make sure you adjust the working directory of the debugger to the folder of the exe. This is in the Debugging tab of the project settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In …

```
*ffd.cFileName
```

remove the `*`.

---

Also remove the call to `Sleep`.

---

Also remove the silly `TEXT` macro call, use wide string literals like `L"blah"`.

---

Oh I forgot, also replace the `do` loop with a `while` loop (or `for` loop), because it's not sure that the `FindFirstFile` call will succeed.

---

Oh, and *important*, for the debug output use `wcout`, not `cout`. The latter doesn't know anything about output of Unicode strings. But `wcout` can handle them.

The output you're getting,

```
52428
```

appears to be `wchar_t` value 0xCCCC, treated as an integer by `cout`, which value indicates uninitialized storage, which implies that the `FindFirstFile` call failed.

---

So, also be sure about the current directory when you run the program. A good idea is to run it from the command line. Then you're sure.

Comment: Excellent this works. Perfectly! 

How would use a String variable with the L(string)?

Comment: @KingJohnno: Depends on the type `String`. With uppercase first letter it's not `std::string`, but it could be MFC/ATL `String` (which does deal properly with wide strings). Anyway, check its documentation.